# WIX Installer: How to keep previous revisions of same application installed

Tags: wix

I installed a revision 1.0 on my system and after some time I make some changes and change the revision to 1.1; Now when I install the revision 1.1 of the application it asks me to remove the previous revision of the application.

How I can instruct WIX that it should keep my old revision installed and install the latest revision without any error?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using simple `Upgrade` logic, (e.g. the `MajorUpgrade` element is great), you only need to do two things:

1. Change your `Product/@Id` guid. That will tell the Windows Installer that you have a new issue of your product.
2. Change your `Product/@UpgradeCode` guid. That will tell the Windows Installer that this product is in a new "family".

Now when you install v1.1 it will leave v1.0 alone and you should end up with both entries in the Add/Remove Programs.